# can not cannot resolve symbol design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i have these two import:

```
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
```

dependency:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0"
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all Android Support dependencies have the same version like below:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
   compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0"
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

   compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Comment: how should I know which version is appropriate?

Comment: always try to have the latest as it propably has bug fixes of previous, but also keep all of support libs in the same version. Does my solution works?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. Problem Will Solve.

```
def object = compile('com.android.support:design:25.1.1')
```